# iOS, Swift, UIImagePicker allows editing crop tool removes transparency. Is there fix?

Tags: ios, swift, image, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

When I get PNG image with transparent background from UIImagePicker it inserts the image with the transparent background just fine as below:

[image]

when I set:

```
imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
```

it allows me to crop as expected in the view provided by UIImagePicker

but then when I press 'Choose' it returns the image with black instead of a transparent background as below:

[image]

The only change between the two results is setting

```
imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
```

and cropping the image in the app.

Is there a way to keep transparency or at least change the black to white when cropping?

I have searched the internet and no mention of this that I can see.

Code:

```
 func showImagePicker() {
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        compImageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        compImageView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        compImageView?.image = pickedImage

    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Show your imagePickerController method.

Comment: You are seeing the saved image in a ImageView or in PhotoLibrary? And why you are setting twice compImageView background?

Comment: @LukeStanyer: please put the code in the original question, not a comment, and format it.

Comment: @AlLelopath Done thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default UIImagePickerController removes the alpha channels in the edited image. To get that transparency you have to edit image yourself. Implement delegate method like this:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {


        if let cropRect = info[UIImagePickerControllerCropRect] as? CGRect {
            if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
                let imageRef: CGImage = image.cgImage!.cropping(to: cropRect)!

                let image1: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)

                imageView.image = image1
                picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: This code does not work if you zoom in the crop tool. It takes the cropRect and applies it to the original image, not the image whilst zoomed.

Comment: UIImagePickerControllerCropRect this return wrong rect if picture captured from camera and get from gallery inside app.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code.

```
import MobileCoreServices //importing for mediaType kUTTypeImage


func showImagePicker() {

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    let mediaTypes: Array<AnyObject> = [kUTTypeImage]
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes as! [String]
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary {

        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {

            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            compImageView?.image = image
        }
    }
}
```